# What is the best way to store a single Sitecore field into two Solr index fields with different types?

Tags: solr, content-search

I have a `Category` field in sitecore and it is currently stored as a `text_general` in Solr. It has this type because I need it to be tokenized and lowercase for searching.

On the other hand I need to do a grouping of the results by this field and for this the field has to be single-valued (single token).

So I think that the best way would be to duplicate this field in Solr and store it with two different types: `category_s` for grouping and `category_t` for searching.

What is the best way to achive this? Is it possible to do this in sitecore config patch without touching the `schema.xml` file?

I use Solr 6.1 with Sitecore 8.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out that we have two options:

### 1. Use Solr to copy field

The [Solr documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/copying-fields.html) says:

> You might want to interpret some document fields in more than one way. Solr has a mechanism for making copies of fields so that you can apply several distinct field types to a single piece of incoming information.
>
> The name of the field you want to copy is the source, and the name of the copy is the destination.

In `schema.xml` it's very easy to make copies of the fields:

```
<copyField source="category_t" dest="category_s"/>
```

### 2. Duplicate field definition in sitecore index config file

Inside `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` or your custom one, you can add your field definition twice. If it is computed field just add it twice like this:

```
<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
    <field fieldName="category" returnType="text">YourNamespace.YourField,YourNamespace</field>
    <field fieldName="category_2" returnType="text">YourNamespace.YourField,YourNamespace</field>
</fields>
```